# undefined reference to "_imp____class name ____ virtual method" On Qt 5.14.1 with QAbstractTableModel

Tags: c++, qt

everyone. Sorry for my English. I know English a little. I've a unsual problem.
I've created AbstractModel inherited from QAbstractTableModel and MyAdvModel inherited from AbstractModel.
This is my code partially.

// abstactmodel.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include "db/utility.hpp"
#include "net/serverloader.hpp"

class QNetworkReply;
class AbstractModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual void parseData(QByteArray*) = 0;
    enum Error{NoError = 0, Null, NoFound, BadJson, NoServerConnection, Unknown};
    explicit AbstractModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void setUrl(const QString&);
    void clearParams();
    void addParam(const QString&, const QVariant&);
    void delParam(const QString&);
    void post();
    void get();
protected:
    ServerLoader* server() const;
private slots:
    void response(QNetworkReply*);
private:
    unique_ptr<ServerLoader> _loader;
    unique_ptr<QVariantMap> _params;
};
```

// myadvmodel.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include "models/abstractmodel.hpp"
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class MyAdvModel :public AbstractModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    static constexpr auto ID_FIELD          = 0;
    static constexpr auto TYPE_FIELD        = 1;
     static constexpr auto ISCLOSED_FIELD    = 2;
//    static constexpr auto ISARRIVED_FIELD   = 3;
    static constexpr auto DATA_FIELD        = 3;
    static constexpr auto STATUS            = 0;
    static constexpr auto LAST              = 6;
    static constexpr auto COLUMNS           = 7;
    enum Type {Driver, Passanger};
    qint32 ID, MAX_ID;
    //                                    id       p/d     isc   isa   datas
    using data_t = std::vector<std::tuple<int32_t, Type, bool,/* bool,*/ std::map<QString, QVariant>>>;
    explicit MyAdvModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyAdvModel() override;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<data_t> _data, _tmp;
private slots:
    void parsed();
public:
    void parseData(QByteArray *) override;
};
```

on compiling time. I get error like this.

> myadvmodel.o:myadvmodel.cpp:(.text+0x1225): undefined reference to > `_imp___ZNK18QAbstractItemModel4dataERK11QModelIndexi'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:182: up_desktop.exe] Error 1
>   20:38:38: Процесс «C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
>   Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта up_desktop (комплект: Desktop MinGW_32)
>   Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»

Thanks for everyone who help me.
again sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. I've solved this problem.

in my myadvmodel.cpp file

in implementation

```
QVariant MyAdvModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
//......
   return AbstractModel::data(index, role);
//......
}
```

this is my error. in my AbstractModel class i've not wrote implementation for data method. in this situation my compiler gived me error for this code `AbstractModel::data(index, role);`. :)
thanks for all, adn sorry for my english.

Comment: There is no `AbstractModel::data`, you did not implement it so you can not call it. There is only `MyAdvModel::data`.

Answer (score 1):

`QAbstractItemModel` is an abstract base class. When subclassing it, *all* pure virtual functions need to be implemented in at least one of the subclasses. In this case, the linker is complaining about the missing [data()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) function, which is pure virtual (`= 0`).

So implement that and all the other pure virtual functions (like `columnCount()`, `index()`, `parent()`, etc.)